# SSHFS-Win - No write permission on Windows system

Tags: permissions, sshfs

I mounted a remote folder locally using SSHFS-Win. I tried both

```
net use H: \\sshfs.r\remoteuser@remoteserver
```

and

```
sshfs remoteuser@remoteserver:/ H:
```

In both cases I can open the H: drive just fine and see all the files, but I can't edit them, even though `remoteuser` is the owner of the files on the remote server, and permissions are cranked all the way up to 777 (normally I'd use 664).

When looking at the properties of the files I'm interested in editing, I get this on my Windows system for "Everyone"

[image]

and this for the user "S-1-0-65534"

[image]

This issue has only started appearing after moving to Windows 11 and a different way of handling accounts on our work systems. It worked fine before.

How can I mount the folder locally so I have the same rights on Windows as `remoteuser` has on the server?

Comment: `S-1-0-65534` is a unmapped SID. So that leaves `Everyone` without the ability to edit the file.  `remoteuser` does not appear in the ACL.  Is there a reason? Suspect `S-1-0-65534` is essentially nobody

Comment: `remoteuser` (different name in real life) only exists on the remote server. But before my switch to Windows 11 and the different account system, `remoteuser` had the same name on the remote system as my account on the Windows system. This is no longer the case, which may be the issue.

Comment: Your ACL does not include the remote user, in fact the only user with permissions, is an unmapped user it appears.  You have an ACL issue.